# Does the presence of an particular object in all the images of data set affect a CNN's performance

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Context: I have partial images of size view of different types of vehicles in my data set ( Partial images because of limited Field Of View of my camera lens ). These partial images cover more than half the vehicle and can be considered as good representative images of the vehicle. The vehicle categories are car, bus, trucks. I always get a wheel of the vehicle in these images and because I am capturing these images during different parts of the day the colour intensity of the wheels vary throughout the day. However a wheel is definitely present in all the images.

Question: I wanted to know if presence of a object in all the images of a data set not logically useful for classification will affect the CNN in any way. Basically I wanted to know before training the CNN should I mask the object i.e black it out in all the images or just let it be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CNN creates a hierarchical decomposition of the image into combinations of various discriminatory patterns. These patterns are learnt during training to find those that separate the classes well.

If an object is present in every image, it is likely that it is not needed to separate the classes and won't be learnt. If there is some variation on the onject that is class dependant, then maybe it will be used. It is really difficult to know what features are important beforehand. Maybe busses have shinier wheels than other cars, and this is something you have not noticed, and thus having the wheel in the image is beneficial.

If you have inadvertently introduced some class specific variation, this can cause a problem for later classification. For example, if you only took photos of busses at night, the network might learn `night = bus` and when you show it a photo of a bus during the day it won't classify correctly.

However, using dropout in the network forces it to learn multiple features for classification, and not just rely on one. So if there is variation, this might not have as big an impact.

I would use the images without blanking anything out. Unless it is something simple such as background removal of particles etc., finding and blacking out the object adds another layer of complexity. You can test if the wheels make a big difference by training the network on the normal images, then classifying a few training examples with the object blacked out and seeing if the class probabilities change.

Focus you energy on doing good data augmentation, that is where you will get the most gains.

You can see an example of which features are learnt on MNIST [in this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/65d9/94fb778a8d9e0f632659fb33a082949a50d3.pdf).